# To extend the life of a cartridge razor blade, should the blade be stored in oil or alcohol?

Tags: everyday-chemistry, water, alloy

I've read varied recommendations about extending the life of a razor blade. Some say should stick the blade in oil when not in use, others say in alcohol, others say in a bowl of rice or silica gel.

I thought this community would be able to settle this:

What is the best (scientifically proven) manner to prevent corrosion of a cartridge razor blade?

I believe my Gillette Mach3 razor blades are stainless steel.

<sup>[The reason for this question is that cartridge blades are not cheap. Some may suggest going to a DE safety razor. I have tried it. It took me 2x as long to shave, so I returned to the cartridges.]</sup>

Comment: Just wash it thoroughly, then dry and keep in a (reasonably) dry place. Steel does not corrode in dry air.

Comment: @permeakra most air will contain at least some water. While this method might be time-saving, it is not the best manner to prevent corrosion, which is what the OP asked.

Comment: @NA > most air will contain at least some water || As long as it doesn't condense, it doesn't matter.

Comment: I don't believe corrosion plays any role at all in the life cycle of Gillette blades. To extend the life of a blade, don't shave with it.

Comment: @permeakra & Ivan Neretin -- I personally witness rust on my Gillette blades. I store my razor in dry air with no treatment. If you get real close, you can see little bits of orange. [This](http://media.tumblr.com/fe6b4dada1034e211f30b5a75acfff28/tumblr_inline_mommftzZkB1qz4rgp.jpg), for example.

Comment: Place the razor (blades attached) down into a cup of rice.

Answer (score 1):

Most blades are dulled by either the edge folding over itself, or small amounts of rust forming. To stop the first problem, you can strop the blade, but that's not really chemistry. For the second one, anything that stops oxygen and water from reaching the blade will stop it from rusting.
Silica gel does absorb moisture,so that would prevent rust from forming, but this would be temporary. You would have to replace it, and even then it might not stop 100% of moisture from reaching the blade.
Oil might prevent water and oxygen from reaching your blade, but it would make it... oily. If you are okay with that then it would probably be a fine solution.
Alcohol would prevent water from reaching the blade pretty well, as well as disinfect it. This might be the best solution to extend your blade's life. Just make sure you use medical grade alcohol.
Finally, blow drying or towel drying your blade after every use will help a lot as well.

Comment: Alcohol would prevent water from reaching the blade pretty well || alcohol may be not as good as water, but pretty close and contains quite a bit of it.

Comment: I currently towel dry the blade. Between oil and alcohol, which one displaces water better? (I don't mind an oily blade.)